# Android Asynctask HTTP not showing results in ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I'm pretty new to Android programming so any help would be great :)
I'm trying to get some dummy data remotely, parse the json response and display it within a listview.

This is the xml layout file i'm trying to use with the list activity:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my http search activity:-

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class searchResultActivity extends ListActivity {

    ListView listview;
    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    String url;
    String fd_name;
    ArrayList<String> listItems;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /*setContentView(R.layout.test);
        listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);*/
        url = "http://pjchambers.comuf.com/index.php";
        new getData().execute();
    }

    public class getData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String...urls) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

            try {
                // Set of http statements setting up the connections to the php
                // and database
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
            }

            // convert response to string
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
                String line = "0";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            // paring data
            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject json_data = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    fd_name = json_data.getString("Name");
                    listItems.add(fd_name);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Results Found",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.d("debug", "- " + listItems.toString());
            return listItems;
        }

        protected void doPostExecute() {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    searchResultActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.list, listItems);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

}
```

I've spent hours trying different methods and approaches, using a few different online tutorials but they all end in the same result. As it stands the app works but the displays are displayed; however if i declare the layout in the onCreate methods the app crashes. any help or advice would be must appreciated, a fresh set of eyes might notice the issue(s) straight away

This is the logcat after I uncommented the two statements

```
05-22 12:12:20.234: D/debug(631): - [The Arena, Empire]
05-22 12:12:42.004: I/dalvikvm(691): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-22 12:12:42.244: I/dalvikvm(691): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-22 12:12:42.404: D/gralloc_goldfish(691): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
05-22 12:12:48.415: I/dalvikvm(691): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-22 12:12:48.424: I/dalvikvm(691): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-22 12:12:50.595: D/AndroidRuntime(691): Shutting down VM
05-22 12:12:50.595: W/dalvikvm(691): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
05-22 12:12:50.614: E/AndroidRuntime(691): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 12:12:50.614: E/AndroidRuntime(691): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project.barcrawl/com.project.barcrawl.searchResultActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
05-22 12:12:50.614: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
05-22 12:12:50.614: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-22 12:12:50.614: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-22 12:12:50.614: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-22 12:12:50.614: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-22 12:12:50.614: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-22 12:12:50.614: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-22 12:12:50.614: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 12:12:50.614: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-22 12:12:50.614: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-22 12:12:50.614: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-22 12:12:50.614: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-22 12:12:50.614: E/AndroidRuntime(691): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
05-22 12:12:50.614: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
05-22 12:12:50.614: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:254)
05-22 12:12:50.614: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
05-22 12:12:50.614: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at com.project.barcrawl.searchResultActivity.onCreate(searchResultActivity.java:41)
05-22 12:12:50.614: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-22 12:12:50.614: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-22 12:12:50.614: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-22 12:12:50.614: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  ... 11 more
05-22 12:12:51.004: I/dalvikvm(691): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-22 12:12:51.024: I/dalvikvm(691): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "if i declare the layout"? you mean the 2 commented lines? can you elaborate on your actual problem and question? and also add the error log. thanks!

Comment: You will need those two lines uncommented first of all to make it work.

Comment: based on logcat where is the problem exactly? could you connect to internet? did you parse it successfully?

Comment: @PJChamb also don't use ListViews `layout_height to "wrap_content"` use `"fill_parent"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your id in the XML should `id="@android:id/list"` then it should work. In your code a new id is created as part of "your" R.class which is different from `android.R.id.list`. Therefore the list view cannot be found and consequently the exception is thrown.

Also the third parameter of the `ArrayAdapter` constructor is supposed to be the id of the text resource to fill with the data. You are passing `R.id.list` which is wrong. For the resource defined by `android.R.id.simple_list_item_1` it should be `android.R.id.text1` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: thanks i've changed the xml but still no luck, I know its something daft i just don't know what it is. At least it itsn't throwing an exception anymore

Comment: I updated my answer with another problem I saw in your code above. If it still doesn't help, it is a good idea to update your original post, so that it is possible to see what exactly is done now.